# Postman response: Multiple actions were found that match the request

Tags: c#, postman, httpresponsemessage

I have two methods with the same name, but different parameters, that should return a `HttpResponseMessage`

```
public HttpResponseMessage ReceivedData(JObject jsonData)
```

and

```
public HttpResponseMessage ReceivedData(double longitude, double latitude)
```

If I'm making a POST request from `Postman` for the second one using

```
http://localhost:6296/api/MyController/ReceivedData?longitude=0&latitude=0
```

everything works ok but for the first one

```
http://localhost:6296/api/MyController/ReceivedData
```

with JSON Body `{"longitude":0, "latitude":0, "otherData":"test"}`
I'm getting

```
"ExceptionMessage": "Multiple actions were found that match the request
```

I don't understand what am I doing wrong.

Comment: You should probably change the second one to be GET, not POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage ReceivedData(JObject jsonData)

[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage ReceivedData(double longitude, double latitude)
```

or if you still want post for both, changed action to ReceivedJsonData for the first one

```
[HttpPost("~/api/My/ReceivedJsonData")]
public HttpResponseMessage ReceivedData(JObject jsonData)
```